# multivariable limit problem involving sine

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

This is a homework problem, but I am having lots of trouble figuring this out. I know homework problems aren't well accepted on this website, but I couldn't find a better place to ask this.
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\sin\left(\frac xy\right)(ax+by)$$

Is there a way to bring the $ax+by$ inside the sine? I'm not so good with trig. But, really the $a,b$ are throwing me off. I'm not even sure if they are integers or what. The book doesn't say anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$-|ax+by|\leq \sin\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)(ax+by)\leq|ax+by|$$

Therefore, by the Squeeze Theorem, $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\sin\left(\frac {x}{y}\right)(ax+by)=0$$

Comment: Where can I find more on the squeeze theorem?

Comment: Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem But there should be something about it in your textbook.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not defined on the $x$-axis. Outside of that, no matter what the constants $a,b$ are, you have a bounded function times a function that approaches $0.$ What else can it do except go to $0?$

Answer (score -2):

$a$ and $b$ are arbitrary real numbers in your problem.

One way to approach this is to see what happens if you approach $(0,0)$ along some arbitrary line.  If the answer for the limit is not independent of the direction of that line, then the limit does not exist.  So write your line as $y=mx$ (no constant; it's got to go through the origin).  (We will have to deal with the case of the line $x=0$ separately to make our set of lines complete.)

Then you have $$f(x,y) = (ax+bmx)\sin \left( \frac{x}{mx} \right)
= (ax+bmx) \sin \left( \frac{1}{mm} \right)$$ which clearly approaches zero as $x \to 0$.

But now look at the line $x=0$, that is, approaching the origin along the $y$ axis. 
$$f(0,y) = (by)\sin \left( \frac{0}{y} \right) $$ which of course is zero everywhere along that line.

So it looks like your limit is zero.

Comment: thank you! This is made it easier to understand.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't exactly true. The limit exists if for every path, the limit exists and is the same. Path can mean line or non-linear shapes that approach the origin as well. While your answer makes it seem like the limit is zero, we still have to prove it. This is where Yagna's solution is correct because it silently accounts for all paths.